# How to Fast View binary/.txt resources?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, resources, resx

I've got .ps1 scripts in my solution which added as .txt files into resources.

I use them in code this way:

`string script = Properties.Resources.TRY_GET_GUEST_SCRIPT_SESSION_RESULT;`

The problem is that I have no instruments to fast view content of this resource - the autogenerated function **TRY_GET_GUEST_SCRIPT_SESSION_RESULT** has only a brief annotation, in addition, has an uncomfortable 'comment' format:

```
        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Param(
        /// [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        /// [guid]
        /// $SessionId
        ...[rest of string was truncated]&quot;
        /// </summary>
```

Which plugins, or code-tricks I can use to fast view (by press F12 - for ex.) resource?

Comment: The binary data probably has a ASCII header.  So use Notepad to look at binary data to see if it contains a ASCII header.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I have PowerShell script files in my resources and I need to fast view it when occurs in the code. As VS hotkey "F12->View Definition", but for resource file:)

Comment: Until you identify the type of file you can't fast view. So you may be able to get the type quickly by looking at the beginning of the file.